# Why can't I use Angular an angular directive's $set function to set ngPattern, ngMinlength and ngMaxlength?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model, angularjs-compile

This is going to sound weird, but, even if it is bad practice or something, how would I get this:

## html:

```
<div ng-controller='CtrlCtrl as ctrlr'>  
  <input account />
  <button ng-disabled='ctrlr.isValid()'>Click</button>
</div>
```

to look like this:

## goal:

```
<div ng-controller='CtrlCtrl as ctrl'>  
 <input type='text' name='derp_herp' ng-model='ctrlr.goal'
   ng-maxlength='10' ng-minlength='3' ng-required='true'
   ng-pattern='/^\d+$/' ng-focus='ctrlr.action()' ng-blur='ctrlr.validate()'
   ng-change='ctrlr.checkValid()'
 />
</div>
```

## WITHOUT doing this:

```
app.directive('accounts', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'inpt.html', // <==== no.
    // template: 'the contents of inpt.html' <==== no.
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, model) {

       //this is where things vary.

    }
  }
```

.
.
.

## A few things I've tried- [(plunkr)](http://embed.plnkr.co/Mc63qu)

#### assume this part is constant:

```
function action(a, b, c){ alert(a); alert(b); alert(c); }

app.directive('accounts', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, model) {

       //this is where things vary.

    }
  }
}]);
```

.
.
.

#### Every iteration of the following (commenting stuff out, etc):

```
 var a, b, c;
  attrs.ngPattern      = /^\d+$/;
  attrs.ngMinlength    = '3';
  attrs.ngMaxlength    = '10';

  attrs.ngChange = function(){
  a=  Object.keys(model);
  b=  Object.keys(elem);
  c=  Object.keys(attrs);
    action(a, b, c );
  }

  $compile(attrs);
  $compile(elem)      
  $compile(scope)
```

## and:

```
   var a, b, c;
      if(model.$invalid){
        elem.addClass('test');
      }
      
      attrs.$set('ngMinlength', '3')
      attrs.$set('ngMaxlength', '3')
      attrs.$set('ngPattern', /^\d+$/);
      $attrs.$set('ngChange','action()');
      

      $compile(attrs);
      $compile(elem)      
      $compile(scope)
```

## and tried with a controller

```
app.controller("CtrlCtrl", ['$scope', '$element','$attrs', '$compile',
function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, $compile) {
  var meta = this, a, b,c;
  this.meta = meta;
  this.ctrlr = meta || {}
  this.ctrlr.modl = "abc";
  $attrs.$set('ngMinlength', '3')
  $attrs.$set('ngMaxlength', '10')
  $attrs.$set('ngPattern', /^\d+$/);
  
  a=  Object.keys($scope);
  b=  Object.keys($elem);
  c=  Object.keys($attrs);
  
  $attrs.$set.ngChange = function(){
    action(a, b, c );
  }

  $compile($scope);
  $compile($attrs);
  $compile($elem)      
  $compile($scope)  
  // console.log(a);
  // console.log(b);
  // console.log(c);

  }
]);
```

I have no idea why this is difficult. The documentation seems detailed enough at first, but good lord is it not enough once you get in the trenches. I've watched every egghead.io video, read so many things... seriously. If this were another language, I'd be teaching it by now.

Comment: It would be super easy with a template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
app.directive('accounts', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, model, transcludeFn) {

        // assume this is all escaped and put together properly as a string 
        var template =    " <input type='text' name='derp_herp' ng-model='ctrlr.goal'
            ng-maxlength='10' ng-minlength='3' ng-required='true'
            ng-pattern='/^\d+$/' ng-focus='ctrlr.action()' ng-blur='ctrlr.validate()'
            ng-change='ctrlr.checkValid()'
            />";

        var e = angular.element(template);
        elem.append(e);
        $compile(e)(scope);

        transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
           elem.append(clone);
        });                       

    }
  }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='CtrlCtrl as ctrlr' accounts>  
  <button ng-disabled='ctrlr.isValid()'>Click</button>
</div>
```

## [EDIT]

If you want to add attribute directives dynamically, you can do that from the compile function of a parent element:

```
app.directive('accounts', [function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(elem, attrs, model) {
         var input = elem.find('input');
         input.attr('ng-min-length', 3);
         input.attr('ng-max-length', 3);
         // etc


    }
  }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='CtrlCtrl as ctrlr' accounts>  
   <input />
   <button ng-disabled='ctrlr.isValid()'>Click</button>    
</div>
```

This works because you are modifying the children of an element ahead of angular compilation. So there is no need for a custom compile step.

## [Edit]

Here's a functioning plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aJhmzT

Comment: I noticed your button isn't in your final HTML. If that's what you wanted, then the transclude bit isn't necessary and you can take that out.

Comment: That would work but it's not what I'm looking for- what I'm trying to do is to add those attributes dynamically with javascript... Dont want to build a string, i want to essentially add the attributes like you would with jQuery('input[name="username"]').attr('ng-pattern', '/^\d+$/');

Comment: When an element is being compiled, you can modify the children as much as you want. It is far more trickier to modify attributes on the current element because you run the risk of re-compiling and re-linking directives. By modifying children only, you don't need a custom compile step.

Comment: awesome! Will that add the attributes to the inputs so it still looks like <input type="text" ng-minlength="3" etc /> ?   my main problem with the way this is normally implemented with angular is that it requires you to have to go through and manually add those attributes to the html which is not dry and also not scaleable. i like the fact that the html is descriptive, i just don't like the method by which the descriptions are added... if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes. By using jQuery to manipulate the DOM ahead of angular compilation, its like the HTML was like that from the beginning.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a shot when i get home and add a plunkr of the results for future people; for now im marking this as the answer; i'll get back if there are any problems. Thanks @pixelbits pixelbits , you rule!

Comment: Good news- i originally thought that didn't work but it turned out that it does work, i just forgot to add an ng-model.  here's the plunk:   http://plnkr.co/edit/aJhmzT

Comment: I was just going to say - you need ng-model for validation to work. That's good to hear.